# Pass EditText Value to Another Activity with Same Style in Android

Tags: android, styles, android-edittext

I am having an editext with the text "**This is a BOLD Text**" and "*This is a ITALIC Text*"

and I am going to pass this edittext value to another activity with same text

In the second activity I am having an TextView, if I display a edittext value in to the text view I am getting like this

"This is a BOLD Text" and "This is a ITALIC Text"

How to pass the edittext value with same style

Comment: You can try to pass text with html tags, like this <b>This is a BOLD Text</b> and <i>This is a ITALIC Text</i>. And set it with textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>This is a BOLD Text</b> and <i>This is a ITALIC Text</i>"));

Comment: @vovkab i am using text editor in Edittext so the user can set the any text to bold,italic or underlined, that text is not pre-defined

Comment: how to get the excat same text from edittext and pass to another activity

Answer (score 0):

Can pass text in html format like:

textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("    **This is a BOLD Text**    "));
or 
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("    *This is a ITALIC Text*    "));